# Missing DLL msoidclil in Azure Web Site

Tags: sharepoint-online, client-object-model, .net, azure

I have an application that accesses and updates SP document libraries. Using SP 2013 COM, it works fine locally. When the code is deployed to and executed in an Azure web site, a file not found exception is thrown re. msoidclil.dll during the creation of a SharePointOnlineCredentials object instance. After much frustration and research, it seems it is not possible to workaround this (however, if someone knows differently please tell me the solution, I'd be most grateful) and I've not been able to figure out / source an alternative means of authentication that will work in the backend code of an Azure web site and access my SP online lists.

Any suggestions or ideas? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

SharePoint client object model (v15) won't work in Azure because it requires Client components and in Azure they aren't installed.
Please check [the link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18724064/sharepoint-azure-msoidclil-dll-missing) to see the detail explanation

As workaround you can try rewrite to last version (v16) it supports portable versions of libraries.

Also you can create own virtual machine and manually install client components.

Comment: Hi,
Microsoft.Sharepoint.Client & Runtime Dlls of Version 16 will work

Answer (score -1):

> Just use Microsoft.Sharepoint.Client & Runtime Dlls of Version 16.
>
> You won't get this error.

[Stackoverflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18724064/sharepoint-azure-msoidclil-dll-missing/28278700#28278700)

Comment: Why Dislike to the answer ? The solution which I post is working with all the mean. Would you please justify the dislike ?